# How to sort, preserving position of blank lines

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a data looks like this

```
<some blah! blah!>|201451|<some blah! blah!>

<some blah! blah!>|201441|<some blah! blah!>

<some blah! blah!>|201431|<some blah! blah!>

<some blah! blah!>|201421|<some blah! blah!>
```

I have to sort it to

```
<some blah! blah!>|201421|<some blah! blah!>

<some blah! blah!>|201431|<some blah! blah!>

<some blah! blah!>|201441|<some blah! blah!>

<some blah! blah!>|201451|<some blah! blah!>
```

I have tried using both these:

```
sort -t"|" -k4.5,4.6 -b data
LC_ALL=c sort -t"|" -k4.5,4.6 -b data
```

but it always gives me

```
<FOUR BLANK SPACE>
<some blah! blah!>|201421|<some blah! blah!>
<some blah! blah!>|201431|<some blah! blah!>
<some blah! blah!>|201441|<some blah! blah!>
<some blah! blah!>|201451|<some blah! blah!>
```

I want to maintain the space with the sorted value. How do I do so??

Basically I have to ignore the line space and not remove them...

Comment: you can't. sort works on a per-line basis, so those blank lines will sort exactly as they are. you'd be better of getting rid of them, then use awk/sed to add blank lines back in.

Comment: then y? have they given the -b option..

Comment: The sample data has only 3 columns, so `-k4.5,4.6` is misleading (for the data shown, it should probably be `-k2.5,2.6`).  It also appears that you want to do a lexicographic sort on just the last two characters of the second column, which means that `<blah>|201501|<blah>` would come before any of the lines shown in the data, and `<blah>|199999|<blah>` would come after any of the lines shown.  Is that really what you want?  Should you just be doing a numeric sort on the second column: `-k2n`?  The `-b` option applies to leading spaces in a field on a line.

Answer (score 4):

Try to execute:

```
sort -t"|" -k4.5,4.6 data | grep -v "^$" | awk '{print $0"\n"}'
```

Comment: With the caveat that the sample data does not have 4 columns (see my comment to the question), this should work and is neat.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with sorting removing blank lines first and then inserting the blank lines back using `sed`:

```
grep -v '^$' <file> |  sort -t'|' -k 4.5,4.6 | sed 's/$/\n/'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish what you need by leading with an `awk` that simply checks if there is content on the line - then follow it up with a `sort` that suits your particular case:

```
$ awk '$1' data_file | sort
some blah! blah!|201421|some blah! blah!
some blah! blah!|201431|some blah! blah!
some blah! blah!|201441|some blah! blah!
some blah! blah!|201451|some blah! blah!
```